# Unit Testing (PHP): When to fake/mock dependencies and when not to

Tags: php, unit-testing

is it better to fake dependencies (for example Doctrine) for unit-tests or to use the real ones?

Comment: Can you give an example of where you would be unsure?

Comment: @halfer The question is clear, although it's just a single line

Comment: @machete I tend to say no, not fake them in general while it could make sense in some situations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a unit test, you use only ONE real instance of a class, and that is the class that you want to test.

ALL dependencies of that class should be mocked, unless there is a reason not to.

Reasons not to mock would be if data objects are being used that have no dependencies itself - you can use the real object and test if it received correct data afterwards.

Another reason not to mock would be if the configuration of the mock is too complicated - in that case, you have a reason to refactor the code instead, because if mocking a class is too complicated, the API of that class might be too complicated, too.

***But the general answer: You want to always mock every dependency, every time.***

I'll give you an example for the "too-complicated-so-refactor" case.

I was using a "Zend_Session_Namespace" object for internal data storage of a model. That instance got injected into the model, so mocking was not an issue.

But the internal implementation of the real "Namespace" class made me mock all the calls to `__set` and `__get` in the correct order of how they were used in the model. And that sucked. Because every time I decided to reorder the reading and writing of a value in my code, I had to change the mocking in the tests, although nothing was broken. Refactoring in the code should not lead to broken tests or force you to change them.

The refactoring added a new object that separates the "Zend_Session_Namespace" from the model. I created an object that extends "ArrayObject" and contains the "Namespace". On creation, all the values got read from the Namespace and added to the ArrayObject, and on every write, the value also gets passed to the Namespace object as well.

I now had the situation that I could use a real extended ArrayObject for all my tests, which in itself only needed an unconfigured mocked instance of "Zend_Session_Namespace", because I did not need to test whether the values were correctly stored in the session when I tested the model. I only needed a data store that gets used inside the model.

To test that the session gets correctly read and written, I have tests for that ArrayObject itself.

So in the end I am using a real instance of the model, and a real instance of the data store together with a mocked instance of "Zend_Session_Namespace" which does nothing. I deliberately chose to separate "model stuff" and "session save stuff" which had been mixed into the model class before -> "single responsibility principle".

The testing really got easier that way. And I'd say that this is also a code smell: If creating and configuring the mock classes is complicated, or needs a lot of changes when you change the tested class, it is time to think about refactoring. There is something wrong there.

Comment: What about dependency trees? Class A depends on Class B, which depends on Class C and D and Class C depends on Class E.
In my case (a CMS), most of the classes have multiple nested dependencies (most of the times ServiceLocators and ObjectManagers). Is there an easy way to mock such trees?

Comment: How would you mock if you can't control object creation inside the system under test?

Comment: When testing class A, you mock class B and do not need to worry about how many C, D, E, F, ... Z will follow after that. When testing class B, you need not worry about A, and have to mock C and D - and again the dependencies of C and D are out of scope.

Comment: @hek2mgl: That's a problem that should be avoided. In your own code this is no issue, in external code you can always add a wrapper layer to work around this.

Comment: @Sven First, I really appreciate that someone answered the question :) I can follow your design approach but I think it is too extreme to say mock all external dependencies. IMO even php native functions like `preg_match()` are external dependencies (are you with me?) ... would you wrap all of them just for testing? (I ask this myself currently - for a subset of functions of course)

Comment: @hek2mgl: It depends. Functions that reliably return the same values depending only on the input need not be mocked. But just think about `time()`. You cannot influence the output - how do you test that 24 hours have passed without waiting a full day?

Comment: @Sven Yeah that's what I meant. If the function is called once then it is no problem to decide: wrap it. But if it is called in a performance critical section then it's hard to decide so. Having this problem in my inotify api. If you need to test the code that would being executed if the core functions fail you need to wrap them (as it is hard to make them fail). I decided to leave some sections with `@codeCoverageIgnore` but I'm not happy with this.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking should be done for a reason. Good reasons are:

- You can not easily make the depended-on-component (DOC) behave as intended for your tests.
- Does calling the DOC cause any non-derministic behaviour (date/time, randomness, network connections)?
- The test setup is overly complex and/or maintenance intensive (like, need for external files)
- The original DOC brings portability problems for your test code.
- Does using the original DOC cause unnacceptably long build / execution times?
- Has the DOC stability (maturity) issues that make the tests unreliable, or, worse, is the DOC not even available yet?

For example, you (typically) don't mock standard library math functions like `sin` or `cos`, because they don't have any of the abovementioned problems.

Why is it recommendable to avoid mocking where unnecessary?

- For one thing, mocking increases test complexity.
- Secondly, mocking makes your tests dependent on the inner workings of your code, namely on how the code interacts with the DOCs.  Would be acceptable for white box tests where the implemented algorithm is tested, but not desirable for black box tests.