# Is MOCKING really useful apart from isolating dependent component testing?

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

So i am developing a security library for Wordpress. Basically building on top of a wordpress core component called [Wordpress nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)
Everything seems to be fine.
Come back to the best practices, i have written a unit testing suite along with the library.
Since my library extends the wordpress noces api, `wordpress` is clearly a dependency in my library.

To achieve isolation when testing my library i used `PHPUnit's mockBuilder` so i can instantiate my dependency class instead of actually instantiating it because it calls an external dependency(`wordpress nonce api`).
Below is my Test class,

```
<?php
namespace nonces;

/**
 * TestWpNonce
 * Test suite for wp-clean-nonces library
 *
 * Wp-clean-nonces is A clean OOP implementation of the Wordpress Nonce library.
 * Copyright (C) 2019  Salim Said.
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * For the complete terms of the GNU General Public License, please see this URL:
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

 * @category  NA
 * @package   NA
 * @author    Salim Said <saliimsaid@gmail.com>
 * @copyright 2019 Salim Said
 * @license   GPL-2.0+ <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
 * @link      ****
 */

if(file_exists('../vendor/autoload.php'))
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
class TestWpNonce extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * This test will create a nonce for a url and verify if a correct
     * url is returned
     *
     * The method asserts for the result returned by createTokenUrl()
     * against a predefined expected return value containing a nonce
     * protected string url
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testCreateTokenUrl()
    {
        $wpNonce = $this->getMockBuilder(WPNonce::class)
            ->getMock();

        $wpNonce->expects($this->once())
            ->method('createTokenUrl')
            ->with($this->equalTo("inpsyde.com?action=publish_postid=2"))
            ->will($this->returnValue('inpsyde.com?action=publish_postid=2&token=297d58f6ae'));

        $this->assertEquals(
            "inpsyde.com?action=publish_postid=2&token=297d58f6ae",
            $wpNonce->createTokenUrl("inpsyde.com?action=publish_postid=2")
        );
    }
}
```

Look at the `testCreateTokenUrl()` method; it creates a mock for the `WPNonce` class, and calls the class method `createTokenUrl()` . This is where things starts to get interesting.

I am defining the input parameter like so `with($this->equalTo("inpsyde.com?action=publish_postid=2"))` and also explicitly expecting a return value as in `->will($this->returnValue('inpsyde.com?action=publish_postid=2&token=297d58f6ae'));`

The `assertEquals()` method will check if the returned value is what i set in the preceding code.

This code helps me test the `createTokenUrl()` in isolation, it doesn't require wordpress(my library's dependency in this case). I can successfully get passing tests without having wordpress installed. That's fine but really what is the whole point of mocking project dependencies if the mock is actually a dummy test that is hard coded with arguments and return types ?

Is there a point of mocking that i am missing or i don't understand ?

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811096/unit-testing-php-when-to-fake-mock-dependencies-and-when-not-to helps.

Comment: The way the test is written now it does indeed make no sense. You shouldn't worry about testing code that is not in your library. Only create tests for the code that you made. Now it would make sense to use a mock like you do now if you had a function of your own that does some validation before calling the WPnonce function. But right now the test is not doing anything useful.

Comment: @DirkScholten what you are saying is , instead of calling WPnonce functions directly i should wrap those function in another functions, validate the arguments and finally call WPnonces functions with validate arguments ? Are you saying that mocking would make sense in such scenario ? Is that what you mean't ?

Comment: @salimsaid Yeah that's what I mean. But don't just wrap it for the sake of wrapping it. Only do that if you actually want to do some validation (or other stuff).

Answer (score 0):

You have to distinguish between the system under test (SUT) and the components that the SUT depends on (depended-on-components, DOCs).  In your case, the SUT seems to be the method `createTokenUrl`.

Mocking is for replacing DOCs.  However, in your test you are mocking the SUT (in fact, you are creating a mock of the class `WPNonce` of which `createTokenUrl` is a member function).  In other words, your call to `$wpNonce->createTokenUrl` will call the mocked method - not a single line of your real method to be tested will be executed in the test.  This obviously does not make sense, but is not a problem of mocking in general.